# Existence of a continuous mapping.

Tags: calculus, continuity, continuous-homomorphisms

Do there exists a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}_{+}$ such that

$$ f(-\log_x y) = x^{-y},$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ ?

Comment: Not for a single-variable $f$, or you have to fix one of the variable and consider families of functions, e.g. $f_x(y)=x^{-x^{-y}}$ such that $f_x(-\log_x(y))=x^{-y}$ $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}_+$ (for a given $x$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you set $y=1$ with $x>0$ you get $f(0)=1/x$, which is definitely not true for all $x>0$.